# Bogus Exception from SSRS when rendering to MHTML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

Environment is SQL Server 2008 *Web* Edition on Windows 2008 server. SSRS is installed and working - ie I can view, refresh and export reports from the report manager.

Due to the constraints of this version I have written a simple ASP.NET wrapper to render the report and email it to me. This works great with HTML or PDF. I want to render it to MHTML and blat this into an email - this also works the first time I run it. On subsequent occasions, unless I stop and restart the SSRS service in the config manager I get:

> You have attempted to use a rendering extension that is either not
>   registered for this report server or it is not supported in this
>   edition of Reporting Services. (rsRenderingExtensionNotFound)

Clearly that is not true, it is registered and it does indeed work. If I switch to rendering to one of the former formats I can run the render as many times as I like. I am wondering if there's some part of the file system being used and maybe a cache file sitting around between times? The symptom is a bit like needing an Application Pool refresh when an ASP.NET app has used a file.

The code that actually executes is:

```
byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("MHTML", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

I'm not sure what to try next, I really want it to render MHTML because when I split that out into an email I get a perfect rendition of my reports directly in the email body.

Help! TIA, M

Answer (score 1):

So the official answer is that it won't work - Web Edition at least disabled the render to MHTML as part of its configuration. It seems to be a bug that this only happens after a report has been processed and indeed it will succeed the first iteration and fail on others.

I ended up rendering to HTML, parsing out the image SRCs, grabbing them as image streams and attaching these to the email, replacing the URLs with cid:s All works very nicely.